# Creating 3D model of human body with python

Tags: python, 3d, blender

I am trying to create a 3d model of a human body using python. My code should generate around 100 different human models.
I want my script needs to: (from most important to least)

1. Be free to develop.
2. Be simply executed - no additional application needs to run.
3. Have control of as many properties of the model as possible - gender, skin color, body hair, gestures, background image, etc.
4. Create a human model as realistic as possible.
5. Be simple to code.

I thought about using Blender with [Mb-lab](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/) add-on. It seemed realistic enough, simple to use, and most importantly - free.
The problem I'm having is: as I said, MB-lab is not exactly a python library but a Blender addon, which requires certain configuration for Blender before using. As much as I searched online and tried - I don't know how to use a Blender addon in an *outside* python script (aka can be executed without opening the blender application) or if it is even possible.

What better solutions are there? Is my solution applicable?